# to check a condition for all the items in two list in python

Tags: python, list

I need to check a condition for all the items in two 1-dimensional lists

For example:

```
L = [12,23,56,123,13,15]
B = [45,89,12,45,19,89]
```

For the above two lists, how do I need to check the condition `if(L[i] > (float(B[i]*1.1)))` where 'i' is the index's starting from index 0 to all the items in the lists (in this case index is 0 to 5).I also need to print the items of list1(L) which fails the condition?

Comment: You mean from `0` to `5`(both inclusive)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to print the ones who are matching, you could use

```
matching = (l > float(b * 1.1) for l, b in zip(L, B))
```

This gives you a generator which you can use as you want. E.g.:

```
for m, l in zip(matching, L):
    if m:
        print l
```

But you could as well directly generate an iterator of matching ones:

```
matching = (l for l, b in zip(L, B) if l > float(b * 1.1))
```

and then print them or just check for emptiness.

Depending on what you want to do, it might be appropriate to change the generator expression to a list comprehension:

```
matching = [l for l, b in zip(L, B) if l > float(b * 1.1)]
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understood you right, you can do this with generator expression and [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function

```
L = [12,23,56,123,13,15]
B = [45,89,12,45,19,89]
all(x[0] > (x[1]*1.1) for x in zip(L, B))
```

or, as Ashwini Chaudhary suggested in comments, with values unpacking:

```
L = [12,23,56,123,13,15]
B = [45,89,12,45,19,89]
all(l > (b * 1.1) for l, b in zip(L, B))
```

To get items from list L which fails the condition:

```
[l for l, b in zip(L, B) if l <= (b * 1.1)]
```

Comment: Use a generator expression, and why the `list` call?

Comment: actually in my code it is list comprehension, but generator would be better, thank you

Comment: `all(... for x, y in zip(L, B)..)`, no need of indexes at all.

Comment: :) you're making this answer for me, I haven't used python for about a week and here it is - not pythonic code in python

Comment: @RomanPekar: You should still remove the excess `list` in your first answer. It's making an extra copy (or, in 3.x, making a list out of a lazy iterator) for no reason, and it makes it more verbose. (If you can't keep things as simple and brief as possible inside a comprehension, it gets harder to follow.) Otherwise, great answer.

Comment: yep, I've removed it in the second one. Actually I've made a list just to see for values in the interactive and than forgot to remove it. I know the difference between streaming and making the whole list. I'll remove it in first one two

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary could you make your own answer and I'll delete mine?

Answer (score 2):

not sure this is what you want but its a cool numpy thing

```
>>> L = numpy.array(L)
>>> B = numpy.array(B)
>>> B < L
array([False, False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
>>> L[L > B* 1.1]
array([ 56, 123])
>>> all(L > B*1.1)
```

Comment: Good answer if `numpy` can be assumed to be installed (e.g. if it is used in the same program anywhere else).